# Why can't I wake up the system after upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: suspend, 16.04

The upgrade to 16.04 appeared to proceed normally, but now I find that when the system goes to sleep, there is no way to wake it up. I have to force a hard power off to reboot the system.

Update October 2016: Still not fixed. I don't know if the graphics card is involved, but it is a ATI Radeon 9800 XT 256MB in a Dell Dimension 4600i PC.

Comment: As of the latest system update, this problem persists. Unlike @user63726 I have an ATI Radeon 9800 XT 256MB Video Graphics Card (driving the stock 17" Dell monitor).

Comment: Well I found [this](http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.in/2016/04/ubuntu-1604-wont-wake-up-from-suspend.html) thread and apparently the 4.5 kernel solves the issue. Worked fine for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) related to the 4.4.0 kernel. You can either wait for the official update, or install 4.4.8 as explained [here](http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/), which fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried kernel  4.4.8 and 4.4.10. It did not solve the issue. I have nvidia 364.19-3 and gtx 980. When I downgraded the driver to 355-11 I do not have this issue.